# Unable to ingest data from flume to hdfs hadoop for logs

Tags: apache, hadoop, hdfs, flume

I am using following configuration for pushing data to hdfs from log file.

```
agent.channels.memory-channel.type = memory
agent.channels.memory-channel.capacity=5000
agent.sources.tail-source.type = exec
agent.sources.tail-source.command = tail -F /home/training/Downloads/log.txt
agent.sources.tail-source.channels = memory-channel
agent.sinks.log-sink.channel = memory-channel
agent.sinks.log-sink.type = logger
agent.sinks.hdfs-sink.channel = memory-channel
agent.sinks.hdfs-sink.type = hdfs
agent.sinks.hdfs-sink.batchSize=10
agent.sinks.hdfs-sink.hdfs.path = hdfs://localhost:8020/user/flume/data/log.txt
agent.sinks.hdfs-sink.hdfs.fileType = DataStream
agent.sinks.hdfs-sink.hdfs.writeFormat = Text
agent.channels = memory-channel
agent.sources = tail-source
agent.sinks = log-sink hdfs-sink
agent.channels = memory-channel
agent.sources = tail-source
agent.sinks = log-sink hdfs-sink
```

I got no error message, but still i m not able to find out the output in hdfs.
on interrupting I can see sink interruption exception & some data of that log file.
I am running following command:

```
flume-ng agent --conf /etc/flume-ng/conf/ --conf-file /etc/flume-ng/conf/flume.conf -Dflume.root.logger=DEBUG,console -n agent;
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue. In my case now it's working. Below is the conf file:

```
#Exec Source
execAgent.sources=e
execAgent.channels=memchannel
execAgent.sinks=HDFS
#channels
execAgent.channels.memchannel.type=file
execAgent.channels.memchannel.capacity = 20000
execAgent.channels.memchannel.transactionCapacity = 1000
#Define Source
execAgent.sources.e.type=org.apache.flume.source.ExecSource
execAgent.sources.e.channels=memchannel
execAgent.sources.e.shell=/bin/bash -c
execAgent.sources.e.fileHeader=false
execAgent.sources.e.fileSuffix=.txt
execAgent.sources.e.command=cat /home/sample.txt
#Define Sink
execAgent.sinks.HDFS.type=hdfs
execAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.path=hdfs://localhost:8020/user/flume/
execAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.fileType=DataStream
execAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.writeFormat=Text
execAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.batchSize=1000
execAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.rollSize=268435
execAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.rollInterval=0
#Bind Source Sink Channel
execAgent.sources.e.channels=memchannel
execAgent.sinks.HDFS.channel=memchannel
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using the prefix configuration when placing files in HDFS:

agent.sinks.hdfs-sink.hdfs.filePrefix = log.out

Answer (score 0):

@bhavesh - Are you sure, the log file(agent.sources.tail-source.command = tail -F /home/training/Downloads/log.txt) keeps appending data ? Since you have used a Tail command with -F, only changed data(within the file) will be dumped into HDFS

Comment: you didn't understand my question first.. well now the story is too old.